# SQL operations between columns

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table called projection_chart that contain these columns:

```
PERCENTAGE    PLANNED     CLEARED       PROJECTED       TOTAL
```

I need to execute a SQL query where I can make the PROJECTED column the value of the `PERCENTAGE` of `PLANNED` and `TOTAL` the value of `PERCENTAGE` of `CLEARED` for the entire table where `media` = digital.

```
UPDATE projection_chart 
SET PROJECTED = PLANNED * PERCENTAGE / 100, 
    TOTAL = CLEARED * PERCENTAGE / 100 
WHERE media = "Digital"
```

Can I use the name of the columns of the table to make the query arithmetic operations? In my head it needs to like loop through each row and perform those tasks, is this possible? if you have any suggestions or a better syntax I'll be forever thankful

Comment: What happens when you run the query?

Comment: @GMB I haven't tested it yet, I have important data and I want to make sure what I want to accomplish is possible

Comment: If all the values you want to do arithmetic on, are in same row - you are right in your approach. If they span multiple rows - you have to group them and apply aggregate functions like SUM

Comment: @AriSingh yes! each row contains the values that will be used in that row so if I execute that it will loop through every row and assign the values that correspond to each row?

Comment: @GabrielDube: so, run the query as a `select` from, to see the results you get.

Comment: @GMB can I still use SET if I use SELECT and it won't update anything?

Comment: @GabrielDube: `select p.*, PLANNED*PERCENTAGE/100 as new_projected, CLEARED*PERCENTAGE/100 as new_total from projection_charts where media = 'Digital'`

Comment: SELECT is for seeing the results WITHOUT updating. Once you are happy with the results, do the UPDATE - which will update what you saw in SELECT. It will update all the rows returned by the select as long as the WHERE clause is the same. Of course, SELECT does not have the SET clause, for UPDATE you have to use SET.

Comment: @GMB I got this: #1051 - Unknown table 'p'

Comment: `... from projection_charts as p where ...`

Comment: p is an alias for the table - you specify an alias by "select ... from projection_charts p where ..." or "select ... from projection_charts as p where ..." depending on your database.

Comment: @AriSingh Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, I ran it and it came with 0 results for some reason, does it matter that the values inside of those columns contain 2 decimals? like 100.92 for example?

Comment: @GMB thank you! I just tested it but it came back empty. I wonder if it has anything to do with the decimals in the columns to perform the operations?

Comment: 0 results means your WHERE clause has an issue. WHERE clause is the same for SELECT and UPDATE. Number or rows returned / updated by a SQL is only dependent on the WHERE clause (the stuff after WHERE), nothing else.

Comment: @AriSingh Thank you it worked like a charm! is there any way to limit the decimals in the new test columns to 2?

Comment: To round a number, you can use something like a "round" function e.g. "SELECT ROUND(colA, 2)" or "SET colA=ROUND(colA/10, 2)". This would round the number to 2 decimal places. Though the exact function name would depend on the database you are using.